# Difference between length() and 60-length() functions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across an oracle function `60-length()` and I found that it differs from regular `length()` function used in Oracle.

If I run,

```
Select length(name) from table_name where id=10;
```

it reruns 16.

But if I run,

```
Select 60-length(name) from table_name where id=10;
```

it returns 44.

I wonder, what is the difference between these two functions. Can anyone please explain?
Also, I found that `30-length(name)` returns **31** and `90-length(name)` returning **74** as a result for the same query. I'm confused with the different results. I already have gone through the *Oracle-docs*, but didn't get any clear idea about these differences.

Comment: 60 - 16 is 44?  :)

Comment: You'll need to show more specific detail about all the various cases you found.  But I suspect these will all be explained by arithmetic.

Comment: right,, I understood.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder, what is the difference between these two functions.

- `length(name)` finds the length of the string in the `name` column.
- `60-length(name)` finds the length of the string in the `name` column and then subtracts that length from 60.

---

> `90-length(name)` returning **74**

If the length of the name is 16 characters then `90 - 16 = 74`.

> `30-length(name)` returns **31**

This one is confusing as `30 - 16 = 14` and not `31`. Are you sure the value is not `47`? Since `47 - 16 = 31`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation,,, I understood now... It's calculating..

Answer (score 1):

`60-length()` is not a function. It's an expression which simply subtracts length of a string from number 60.

If length is 20, then `60 - length = 60 - 20 = 40`.